# Orchard Warmup module not working

Tags: orchardcms

I have a site that I just pushed to production that's experiencing significant lag, load times of 15+ seconds on some pages.

To try and fix that I've installed the cache, syscache and warmup modules. The first two seem to have minimal effect and, unfortunately, the warmup module seems to be not working. It's returning a status of 0 for all the paths I've entered.

Looking through the code it seems this essentially means the WebRequest is failing, any thoughts on what trees to bark up?

Comment: 15 seconds is not normal. You should profile (Mini-Profiler is a good start if you don't have access to a full profiler), and figure out what's slowing it down so much.

Comment: Betrand- Is there any trick to getting it running? I downloaded the source (our firewall blocks .nupkg for some reason), dropped it in the modules folder and enabled it... but no miniprofiler widget to be seen.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get sqlprofiler installed... And my pages are very chatty. Looks like my heavy use of the query navigation items is a big part of it, anyway to force those to cache across the application?

Comment: Caching the navigation did the trick, this module was a life saver https://navigationcache.codeplex.com. Frustrating that the Output Caching didn't cover this application wide...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the host headers were deemed unsafe and getting blocked. Fix is to add

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

to your web.config.

Didn't solve much in terms of performance though...